# Specify Order of Variadic Generic Arguments for Variable Parameters in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, variadic

I'm trying to do something that feels absurd, but I've gotten so close I feel it must be possible, I just can't quite get it.

I'm trying to create a generic function type such that assigning the function type

```ts
const typedFunction: Generic<
    SomeObject,
    ['keys', 'in', 'that', 'object']
>;
```

will produce a function whose arguments are typed, exactly:

```ts
(
    arg0: typeof SomeObject['keys'],
    arg1: typeof SomeObject['in'],
    arg2: typeof SomeObject['that'],
    arg3: typeof SomeObject['object']
)
```

I've arrived at two near-but-not-quite solutions;

1.

```ts
declare type SomeGeneric<
   T,
   Params extends (T[keyof T])[]
> = (...args: Params) => ReturnType;
```

Which preserves the order, but forces me to specify Params in a very ugly way:

```ts
const someFunction: SomeGeneric<
    SomeObject,
    [SomeObject['keys'], SomeObject['in'], ...]
> = (arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3) => { ... };
```

This is obviously verbose to the point of being useless, as I could just specify them directly that way.

2.

```ts
declare type SomeGeneric<
    T,
    Params extends (keyof T)[]
> = (...args: T[Params[number]][]) => ReturnType;
```

But, since `Params[number]` refers to *any* member of `Params`, this turns every argument of `SomeGeneric<SomeObject, ['keys', 'in', 'that', 'object']>` into a union type of `SomeObject['keys'] | SomeObject['in'] | ...`

What I'd like to know is if there's some way to specify that I want `SomeObject` to be accessed via the keys provided *in order*, something like `...args: SomeObject[...Params[number]]` if such syntax weren't nonsensical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close with your 2nd attempt.

You need to use [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to map over the elements in `Params`. For each index `I` you can get the array element `Params[I]` which can be used to `T`.

Note that using a mapped type to map over tuple also produces a tuple since [3.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html). This is essential here since a spread parameter type must be a tuple type.

```
declare type SomeGeneric<
   T,
   Params extends (keyof T)[]
> = (...args: { [I in keyof Params]: T[Params[I]] }) => void;


type Test = {
    a: string
    b: number
    c: Date
}

const someFunction: SomeGeneric<Test, ["a", "b", "c"]> = (
    arg0, // string
    arg1, // number
    arg2  // Date
) => {}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAXAngBwQZQPYFsQHEQA7EGASzAB4AoeOgFQBpa6AFWKHAZ3hAA9ExYDwAUAaxDIsAM3j0AlAG0AutQB88ALzwRAOn2wA5lwBc8AN7xFASXhki8CVNnsYnLsrP1Fr9zeXK8AC+8loaAG5YZMAA3NTxKOhyIFyIWhYsdFBmqeREhpnwAEZmRACuOEWkhWBmACJQgtRB8WBYRKnwXLggAGJlRGCIZO1m2HiEJORU9CmIjFYARFCLC4tFq-CLYIvKGtoihUYADAsA9GddiHkFdFkwhgCM55flldV38EYATHQX8A0mqFNBpzEEgA)

Comment: Aha, I was trying to use `X in keyof Y` but I had no idea you could specify variable arguments as an *object* type rather than an array type. Thank you!

Comment: @JMA - it is a tuple type. See the 3rd paragraph (that I just edited in)

Comment: that makes more sense; the fixed/const nature of tuples is exactly why this works, and I understand that now.